# Mass transit cancel consumer job when pod shuts down or restarts

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, .net-6.0, masstransit

I have the following problem with mass transit on a .Net app.

I have a class that implements the IConsumer<> interface and consumes messages from a RabbitMQ queue. The app is a running as pod on a Kubernetes cluster and it can scale horizontally so we can have multiple instances of the app running at the same time if needed.

I am also injecting the service with:

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit()
```

where I am configuring the Consumer, RabbitMQ Host and the receive endpoint.

When a pod shuts down / restarts for whatever reason and because there is an actually delay from the moment that the pod receives the SIGTERM signal and the moment that it completely shutsdown, I want to be able to:

- notify a method that I am calling from the consumer that the task has been cancelled;
- stop all the other consumers which just started processing the message from actually calling that method;

Here is what I have right now, which doesn't work mainly because the cancellation token from the context is not changing states:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<NotificationMessage> context)
{
  try
  {
    if (context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }

    // call method that also receives the Cancellation Token
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
      when (ex is OperationCanceledException || ex is TaskCanceledException)
  {
    // log it

    throw;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideea how I can achive this sort of behavior.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the [host options](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#host-options) in MassTransit so that when the generic host terminates, the bus and its consumers can be canceled as well.

Setting `ConsumerStopTimeout` to a value lower than `StopTimeout` will signal the consumers that the bus is stopping via the `CancellationToken` property on `ConsumeContext`.

Also, be sure to set the .NET host stop timeout as well, which is also documented at the above link.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the answer, it seems to work! Just one question, I have configured the following timeouts, do you have any recommendation on some good Timeout values?

options.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
options.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
options.ConsumerStopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)

Comment: Those timeouts are what I'd consider way too low. Think 30/60, not 3/5.